# Cloud Functions for Firestore: accessing parent collection data

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Many blogs suggest to switch to Cloud Firestore because it's easy and well secured. Coming from Realtime Database and back when using Functions + RD it was easy to navigate through document triggers, like `ref.parent`

My setup is like this:

> - Users
>
>   - {userid}
>
>     - last_seen: "data"
>     - {forms}
>
>       - {formid}

However, i have added a document trigger with `onCreate`, and i want to get the value of `last_seen`:

```
exports.updateUser = functions.firestore.document('users/{userId}/forms/{formid}').onCreate((snap, context) => {

    const newValue = snap.data();
    console.log("test value : " + newValue.test); // works
    console.log("form id: " + context.params.formid); // works
    console.log("user last seen : " + newValue.last_seen); // doesn't work, can't access the parent collection data


});
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I totally get the confusion with the switch to Firestore but it's almost the exact same way in this case.

In realtime, you have the snapshot:

```
exports.doStuff = functions.database.ref('/users/{userId}/forms/{formId}')
    .onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
    const ref = snapshot.ref;
    const userRef = ref.parent.parent;
    userRef.once('value').then(parentSnap => {
        const user = parentSnap.val();
        const lastSeen = user.last_seen;
    });
});
```

In Firestore:

```
exports.doStuff = functions.firestore.document.onCreate('/users/{userId}/forms/{formId}')
    .onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
    const ref = snapshot.ref;
    const userRef = ref.parent.parent;
    userRef.get().then(parentSnap => {
        const user = parentSnap.data();
        const lastSeen = user.last_seen;
    });
});
```

Another thing to consider is you are passing the `userId` in your params so you could just build your own DocumentReference (assuming you're also using firebaseAdmin)

```
functions.firestore.document.onCreate('/users/{userId}/forms/{formId}')
    .onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
    const userId = context.params.userId;
    const userRef = firebaseAdmin.firestore().collection('users').doc(userId);
    userRef.get().then(parentSnap => {
        const user = parentSnap.data();
        const lastSeen = user.last_seen;
    });
});
```

It also allows you to decouple your logic for functions you may use often, consider it as a "helper" method: (NOTE, I switched to async/await on accident, it's a bit cleaner)

```
functions.firestore.document.onCreate('/users/{userId}/forms/{formId}')
    .onCreate(async (snapshot, context) => {
    const userId = context.params.userId;
    const lastSeen = await getLastSeen(userId);
});

// == Helper Functions ==-------------------
export async getLastSeen(userId) {
    if (!userId) return Promise.reject('no userId');
    // User Ref
    const userSnap = await firebaseAdmin.firestore().collection('users').doc(userId).get();
    return userSnap.data().last_seen;
}
```

Now you can use `getLastSeen()` whenever you need it, and if you make a change you only have to adjust that one function. If it's not something you call often then don't worry about it, but I would consider maybe a `getUser()` helper...

Comment: such a clean, concise answer, thank you so much for the tips

Answer (score 2):

In your code, `snap` is a [DocumentSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.firestore.DocumentSnapshot) type object.  As you can see from the linked API documentation, there is a [`ref`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.firestore.DocumentSnapshot#ref) property on that object that gets you a [DocumentReference](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/0.20.x/DocumentReference) object pointing to the document that was added.  That object has [`parent`](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/0.20.x/DocumentReference#parent) property that gives you a [CollectionReference](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/0.20.x/CollectionReference) that points to the collection where the document exists, which also has a [`parent`](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/0.20.x/CollectionReference#parent) property.  So, use these properties to navigate around your database as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Get the reference where the change took place, move 2 levels up and capture data using `ref.once()` function:

```js
exports.updateUser = functions.firestore.document('users/{userId}/forms/{formid}').onCreate( async (snap, context) => {

    // Get the reference where the change took place
    const changeRef = snap.after.ref;

    // Move to grandad level (2 levels up)
    const userIdRef = changeRef.parent.parent;

    // Capture data
    const snapshot = await userIdRef.once('value');

    // Get variable
    const lastSeen = snapshot.val().last_seen;

    // Do your stuff...

    return null;

});
```